# Detecting mouse events on drag in EaselJS across shapes

Tags: javascript, html, easeljs

I have a chessboard like UI, wherein when I drag across check squares I need to EaselJS to detect my shapes(different squares) .I have hooked up those shapes with onMouseMove event handler. However I see that which ever shape gets clicked on mouse down that same shapes keeps emitting the onmousemove event even though I have moved outside the surface area of that shape and onto another shape. How can I have events that listen when I move out of the shape and into another shape using drag/touch or mouse drag?

Comment: It usually works as you want it to, so my initial guess is that the listeners are not hooked up correctly, can you post a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

The mousemove events come from the shape you clicked on, so the target will always be that initial clicked shape.

To determine what is currently under the mouse, use the `getObjectUnderPoint` or `getObjectsUnderPoint` APIs.

http://www.createjs.com/Docs/EaselJS/classes/Container.html#method_getObjectsUnderPoint